# Import tensorflow failed with Error no attribute 'HIDDEN_ATTRIBUTE'

Tags: tensorflow

Import failing with following error :

C:\Users\bhush>py -3.6-64
Python 3.6.6 (v3.6.6:4cf1f54eb7, Jun 27 2018, 03:37:03) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

> > > import tensorflow as tf
> > >       Traceback (most recent call last):
> > >         File "", line 1, in 
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 34, in 
> > >           from tensorflow._api.v1 import compat
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v1\compat__init__.py", line 21, in 
> > >           from tensorflow._api.v1.compat import v1
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_api\v1\compat\v1__init__.py", line 643, in 
> > >           'tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.api._v1.estimator'))
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\tools\component_api_helper.py", line 56, in package_hook
> > >           child_pkg = importlib.import_module(child_package_str)
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
> > >           return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator__init__.py", line 8, in 
> > >           from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1 import estimator
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator_api\v1\estimator__init__.py", line 8, in 
> > >           from tensorflow_estimator._api.v1.estimator import experimental
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator_api\v1\estimator\experimental__init__.py", line 8, in 
> > >           from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.dnn import dnn_logit_fn_builder
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator__init__.py", line 25, in 
> > >           import tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.estimator_lib
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator_lib.py", line 22, in 
> > >           from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator.canned.baseline import BaselineClassifier
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\canned\baseline.py", line 65, in 
> > >           from tensorflow_estimator.python.estimator import estimator
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1708, in 
> > >           class EstimatorV2(Estimator):
> > >         File "C:\Users\bhush\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\site-packages\tensorflow_estimator\python\estimator\estimator.py", line 1711, in EstimatorV2
> > >           export_savedmodel = deprecation.HIDDEN_ATTRIBUTE
> > >       AttributeError: module 'tensorflow.python.util.deprecation' has no attribute 'HIDDEN_ATTRIBUTE'

I was trying to install tensorflow nightly build. I have CUDA 10 and cuDNN 7.3.0.29. TensortFlow py -3.6–64 -m pip install tf-nightly-gpu

Then I do import tensorflow I get above stack trace. I am trying to understand possible reasons for failure.

Comment: Please add more context regarding what have you tried and on doing what thing you are getting this error.

Comment: Edited description.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same error, then I tried doing

```
pip install tf-nightly-2.0-preview --ignore-installed
```

It solved this issue, even though I met with others. I think libraries in your environment has version clash, so this should fix your issue, as it won't reinstall installed libraries.

This link might help to find a compatible version of CUDA and Tensorflow.

[Nightly build list](https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source)

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar error. You can try
`pip install -q tensorflow==2.0.0-alpha0`

Comment: installed an older version of  Tensorflow with this command and corresponding CUDA version. It worked. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Could be an issue with the nightly build on Windows. I could only get this work by reverting back to the last stable GPU build with this command

```
pip3 install --force-reinstall tensorflow-gpu
```